# Не работает регулярка в PHP в многострочном режиме

Tags: php

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста, почему регулярка не работает. В документации пишут, что если поставить параметр x, то можно регулярные выражения переносить на сл строки и этот параметр заставит не учитывать пробелы и переносы строк и даже комментарии. Но не работает =(

Вот сама регулярка

```
preg_match_all('{
<div class=\"a--atext atext\" itemprop=\"text\">(.*?)<\/div>
}uxis',$result,$mAnswers);
```

Comment: вроде за это отвечал флаг `m`, но в конкретном случае у вас еще учитваются и переводы строки перед/после элемента, что навряд ли является желаемым поведением

Comment: плюс, емнип, управляющие символы регулярки должны быть идентичными, здесь же это две разных скобки

Comment: вы поняли что в документации шла речь об переносах в самом регулярном выражении, а не в тексте, который вы им разбираете?

Comment: или вы про это и пишите? зы: уберите лишнее экранирование двойных кавычек и слешей.

Comment: Что такое емнип?

Comment: Да я понял, я именно про перенос строк в самой регулярке - ибо строк возможно будет много и неудобно их все в 1ну пихать.

Answer (score 2):

Если необходимо иметь возможность разбивать само регулярное выражение на строки, то для `$result = '<div class="a--atext atext" itemprop="text">Some Text</div>';` подойдет такое выражение (необходимо экранировать значимые пробелы):

```
preg_match_all('@
<div\ class="a--atext\ atext"\ itemprop="text">(.*?)</div>
@uxis', $result, $mAnswers);
```

и `$mAnswers` будет содержать:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <div class="a--atext atext" itemprop="text">Some Text</div>
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some Text
        )
)
```

Но если имеется в виду, что сама искомая строка может содержать переводы строк:

```
$result = '<div class="a--atext atext" itemprop="text">
  Some Text 1
  Some Text 2
  Some Text 3
</div>';
```

то подойдет следующее выражение:

```
preg_match_all('@<div class="a--atext atext" itemprop="text">(.*?)</div>@uis', $result, $mAnswers);
```

и $mAnswers будет содержать:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <div class="a--atext atext" itemprop="text">
  Some Text 1
  Some Text 2
  Some Text 3
</div>
    )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
  Some Text 1
  Some Text 2
  Some Text 3

        )
)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы очень мне помогли! Здоровья вам!!! :)